# Outlook RibbonXML SelectionChange event not raised creating new mail

Tags: c#, outlook, ribbon

I am working on a Ribbon XML addin for Outlook. I am having a problem resetting my toggle button when user creates new mail. It seems this event handler SelectionChange is not called when creating a new mail.

_application.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange += MainRibbon_SelectionChange;

```
private void MainRibbon_SelectionChange()
{
  _ribbon.Invalidate();
}
```

What event should i raise to trigger the MainRibbon_SelectionChange when ussr creates new mail message?

THanks so mmuch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Explorer.InlineResponse` event and `Application.Inspectors.NewInspector` in case of a new inspector.